# Происхождение "вращаться в обществе" — почему "вращаться"?

Tags: фразеология

Перлы из школьных сочинений наталкивают на размышления. На сей раз: "Пушкин вращался в обществе и вращал там свою жену".
Звучит смешно именно то, что он "вращал" жену, но то, что "вращался" сам, для слуха привычно. Но, если вдуматься: а почему именно "вращался"?

Comment: Я этот перл читаю в разных журналах лет двадцать, не меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Толковый словарь под ред. C. И. Ожегова и Н.Ю.Шведовой
ВРАЩАТЬСЯ, -аюсь, -аешься; несов. 1. То же, что вертеться (в 1 знач.).Земля вращается вокруг своей оси. 2. Постоянно, часто бывать в какой-н.среде или в обществе ка-ких-н. людей. В. в ученых кругах. В. среди молодежи.II сущ. вращение, -я, ср. II прил. вращательный, -ая, -ое (к 1 знач.).Вращательные движения.
   Школьник в сочинении смешал 2 значения этого слова :)

Answer (score 1):

Да, школьники могут такое выдать!Ну, данный школьник в чём-то и прав: вращал же Пушкин там свою жену в вальсе, например:-)))